# Read & Save setting an array in array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I try to load this array out from my save setting "Mybookmarks", and try to write it in a table. That is in the setting =>

```
 [["name" : "apple", "url": "http://www.apple.de"],
  ["name" : "youtube", "url": "http://www.youtube.de"]]
```

But it doesn't work, it said always crash. I want to load this kind of array and write it in a tableview.
Any idea on how to fix this so that it can read this from my "var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()".

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// create references to the items on the storyboard
// so that we can animate their properties
var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()

var objects = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    //read
    if let testArray : AnyObject? = defaults.objectForKey("Mybookmarks") {
        var objects : [NSString] = testArray! as! [NSString]
        println("\(testArray)")
    }

    tableView.frame         =   CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, view.frame.height);
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.objects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
    let object = self.objects[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = object["name"]!
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
}
```

Comment: if `println("\(testArray)")` is printing the correct value, try moving `tableView.delegate      =   self` and `tableView.dataSource    =   self` to `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

the type of the array is an array of dictionaries `[[String:String]]` rather than array of strings `[String]`

```
var objects = [[String:String]]()

...

if let testArray : AnyObject? = defaults.objectForKey("Mybookmarks") {
    objects = testArray as! [[String:String]]  
}
```

Edit:

and connect the tableview instance in Interface Builder with an IBOutlet.
The instance you're creating with `var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()` is a brand new instance, it's different from those in IB

Comment: I receive now this error "Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments" on this line "cell.textLabel?.text = object["name"]!"

Comment: I edited the post. The array of dictionaries is guaranteed to be valid and the var keyword must be deleted (scope error)

Comment: I just tested the code successfully in a playground. What is the result of `println(object)` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: If I comment the object line, and add the println(object) line. It give me this result: {
    name = Apple;
    url = "https://www.apple.de";
}

Comment: the table view instance causes the problem, see the edit in the post

Comment: the table is not in the UI (in main.storyboard), the table is programmable created.

Comment: OK, then there must be another issue. The main question of this topic to put the bookmarks into the `objects` variable is answered

Comment: but that is part of the answer, because it doesn't write it in the table. :(

Comment: nevermind I see that this is not in [String:String]. This must be in let object: [String:String] = self.objects[indexPath.row]
        and now it works

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I see that this is not in [String:String]. This must be in let object:
[String:String] = self.objects[indexPath.row]
and now it works